# hibernate and jpa weirdness; unexpected lazy fetching

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, jpa

I'm using a rather old version of Hibernate (3.2.4) so it's possible this is related to that.  Unfortunately the project requirements prevent me from upgrading.

I have a class Foo with many-to-one association to Bar.  The association is flagged:

```
lazy="false" fetch="join"
```

Now when I do something like:

```
em.find(Foo.class, id);
```

I get the expected result:  a *single* statement joining the FOO table with the BAR table.  However, when I try something like:

```
em.createQuery("select f from Foo where f.id = :id")
.setParameter("id", id)
.getSingleResult();
```

I get the single join followed by an additional select query against BAR.  The second query seems to be *entirely superfluous*; all the data needed to eagerly populate an instance of Foo should have been available from the initial join.  It looks roughly like this:

```
select f.id, f.xyz, ..., b.id, b.xyz, ... 
from foo f 
join bar b on b.id = f.bar_id 
where f.id = ?

select b.id, b.xyz, ... 
from bar b 
where b.id = ?
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't respect `fetch = "join"` when executing HQL queries. From the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-custom):

> The fetch strategy defined in the mapping document affects:
>
> - retrieval via get() or load()
> - retrieval that happens implicitly when an association is navigated
> - Criteria queries
> - HQL queries if subselect fetching is used

In the case of HQL queries you have to use `left join fetch`:

```
em.createQuery("select f from Foo f left join fetch f.bar where f.id = :id")
    .setParameter("id", id)
    .getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Yes, I realized this after the fact.  Is there a way in HQL/JPA-QL to indicate "join fetch all associations" so I don't have to enumerate them?  It seems Hibernate supports this via Criteria queries (setFetchMode) but I'm constrained to the JPA interface.

Comment: @user190758: I guess no, since Hibernate has much more freedom when constructing Criteria queries than when translating HQL queries.

Comment: Man that sucks.  Know if its possible to "convert" an HQL query to a criteria instance that I could programmatically call setFetchMode() on?  Or possibly a hint I could pass Hibernate via the JPA setHint() method?